# Tkinter <KP_Enter> binding unresponsive

Tags: python, user-interface, lambda, tkinter, bind

I have read a fair few other threads that seemed to be dealing with this problem, but none of them gave me a fix. The code for the button in question is:

```
#equals button
cmd = lambda x='=': self.Click(x)
self.equals_button = Button(self.MasterFrame, text='=', width=12,
                            height=2, command=cmd)
self.equals_button.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S,
                        ipadx=2, padx=2, pady=2)
self.equals_button.bind("<KP_Enter>", cmd)
```

I tried calling .focus_set() on the button at various stages in the code but to no avail(it didn't work). This code appears in the `__init__` method. Earlier in the method, I call `.focus_set()` on another widget instance which is necessary. I tried calling this bind on the Master frame also, along with focus_set both on the Master frame and the button itself. None of this has helped. I am not getting any error messages.
    The button does work when I mouse-click on it. It simply doesn't respond to pressing the KP_Enter. I would like it to do both.

Comment: Does binding "<KP_Enter>" work on any other widgets? Maybe the name is wrong. Have you tried "<Return>" instead?

Comment: <Return> only produced a response when I bound it to my root. It responded with <Tkinter.Event instance at 0x00000000031B7508> on my Entry widget. When the '=' is passed to cmd, it causes output to the Entry widget, self.screenFrame

Comment: That's probably because when you `bind`, the first argument passed to your lambda will be the Event object. Perhaps you should do `cmd = lambda event, x='=': self.Click(x)`. Or even just `cmd = lambda event: self.Click('=')`.

Comment: ok, I used the first of your suggested lambdas above. I also have the button itself bound to <Enter>. It actually works, but it takes a long time to respond. Where should I be setting the focus?

Comment: I set it initially to the Entry widget, a screen, so that users can instantly enter digits from the keypad without having to click into it. So, I was thinking maybe the fact that focus is already set somewhere is conflicting with another attempt to set focus on this button. Tabbing to the button actually fixes my problem now, just isn't working in the code for some reason.

Comment: Confusingly, "<Enter>" doesn't trigger when the user presses Enter. From the tutorial An Introduction To Tkinter: "`<Enter>`: The mouse pointer entered the widget (this event doesn’t mean that the user pressed the Enter key!)."

Comment: I am stupid today, I had read that earlier today! And here I was wondering what the difference between <Enter> and <Return> could be. <Return> is working

Comment: Are you aware that when you put a binding to a key onto a button, that event will only fire if the keyboard focus is on that button? And typically, to get focus on a button you'll have to either click on it, or press Tab one or more times to move focus to that widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Kevin I resolved this issue. Binding to `<KP_Enter>` wasn't working, but binding instead to `<Return>` was responding, although, still not working correctly. So, Instead of binding the `self.equals_button`, I bound the Entry widget itself to `<Return>`, such that it only responds to the key-press when it is focused upon with `.focus_set()`.
    The data in the Entry widget was used as a param for the function in the `.bind()` params. So now I have the same function bound, first to the Entry widget when I press Enter(this includes keypad enter on my system, which is what I wanted), and again in the widget instantiation statement(`button=Button(etc.etc.command=myfunc)`), allowing me to have the same functionality by clicking with the mouse and by pressing the keypad enter key. Thanks again Kevin.

Answer (score 2):

You probably code under windows.
KP_Enter is only valid on Unix (linux, bsd...).
Under windows, Return and KP_Enter are the same key: Return