# How to bind the other "Enter" on the keyboard in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, enter

I am writing a tkinter app in python 3.12.0 **(on windows)** and I want to bind **the other "Enter"** (Which is in Num-Lock part of keyboard) that when I press it, send my message.
I am using a Text Widget and I need the main Enter for break line.
I hove solved my problem with beneath code and it works on my system; But I'm looking for a better solution and I don't know if this function works on other systems or even if it works on a different OS.

```
def foo(event=None):
if not (event.keysym=="Return" and event.state in [
    262144, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock Off
    262146, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock Off
    262152, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock On , Scroll Lock Off
    262154, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock On , Scroll Lock Off
    262176, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock On
    262178, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock On
    262184, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock On , Scroll Lock On
    262186, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock On , Scroll Lock On
    ]):
    return
# do the code
```

My problem is already solved. I just want to know is there a better way to bind the other "Enter"?

---

Edit:
As I told in the first place: I want to use only the second Enter button and I think I couldn't get my point across.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
def foo(event=None):
    print(event) 
    print(event.state)
    # to bind only to other Enter, but not the main Enter:
    if event!=None and (not (event.keysym=="Return" and event.state in [
        262144, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock Off
        262146, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock Off
        262152, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock On , Scroll Lock Off
        262154, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock On , Scroll Lock Off
        262176, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock On
        262178, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock Off, Scroll Lock On
        262184, # Caps Lock Off, Num Lock On , Scroll Lock On
        262186, # Caps Lock On , Num Lock On , Scroll Lock On
        ])):
        return
    print("Yey!")

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=60, height=8)
text.bind('<Key>', foo)
text.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Send', command=foo).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Please check others' answers.

Comment: Try binding event `<KP_Enter>`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. but it's not working.

Comment: @Mohammad hi. Do you want to make the printing of "Yey!" only happen if keypad `entry` is pressed? I mean, if you, for example, in addition to `entry` key press `shift` or `ctrl` keys, "Yey!" will not be printed. Is that what you want or would you like "Yey!" appears always despite the other pressed keys?

Comment: I'm not sure why `KP_Enter` isn't working on Windows, and unfortunately all of my keyboards are TKL so I can't easily test this for you, but you should be able to find the correct keysym to bind using `root.bind('<Key>', lambda e: print(e))` as a quick test. Just press the keypad enter key and when the event gets printed you'll be able to see the name.

Comment: @Danya K. I want to send my message by pressing only the second enter. Whether or not the lock keys are On or Off. But I want to use main Enter to place break ("\n") in my text.

Comment: @JRiggles I've done that and both the Enters print 'Return' and also their type is str. The only different between them is the state. for more detail, take a look at OldBoy comments and my answers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def foo(event=None):
    if event and (not (event.keysym == "Return" and (event.state & 262144))):
        return
    print("Yey!")
```

However, if you press the keypad `Enter` along with additional keys such as `shift`, `ctrl`, `alt` or others, printing will still occur.
If you want printing to happen when you only press keypad `Enter` and don't press any additional keys (other than various locks), try this code:

```
def foo(event=None):
    if event and (not (event.keysym == "Return" and (event.state & 524245) == 262144)):
        return
    print("Yey!")
```

Just recently I've found a third option: Try to use the bind on `Extended-Return`:

```
def foo(event=None):
    print("Yey!")


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=60, height=8)
text.bind('<Extended-Return>', foo)
…
```

Should give the same result as the first example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is no need to explain the code. I've understood what you've done. You have used bitwise "and" to find out that is one of the locks' On or Off. So Interesting and wise method. The first one was OK to me. But the second one is more than I needed and is great. Thanks again. I'm wating for other answers to see if there is a keywoard like KP_Enter which will work on windows for a couple of days. If there was not, I will mark your answer as the best one.

Comment: @Mohammad can you check the third option I've just added to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

See [tkinter Key names](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/key-names.html), for a list of the relevant bindings. As you can see `KP-Enter` is the key on the keypad, and `Return` is the one on the main keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the link you sent. But it's not working yet. When I use print(event), the result is: <KeyPress event send_event=True state=Mod1|0x40000 keysym=Return keycode=13 char='\r' x=344 y=45>. The only difference between two enter is the state and the keysym is still "Return" not KP_Enter.

Comment: I have googled KP_Enter and the point is that I am using windows and it does not work on windows. Thanks anyway. the link was good. and I have eddited the question and bold Windows. Thanks.

Comment: @Mohammad The `0x40000` added to the state value identifies which of  the two keys has been pressed. Unfortunately this documentation is rather old so it may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: know that 0x40000 in hex will be 262144 in decimal and I wrote that list for this reason. But I am looking for a simple method like KP_Enter that everybody told and not working on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `<KP_Enter>` should work. Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def send_message(event):
    print("message sent!")
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.bind("<KP_Enter>", send_message)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP has already tested that it didn't work in Windows.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Not working as I said. thanks anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142319/tkinter-kp-enter-binding-unresponsive